# SearchView launches searchable activity without intent

Tags: android, android-intent, searchview

I am using a SearchView for starting a new activity that shows the search results. I have followed the following sources:

- Android tutorial: [Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)
- SO: [Start new activity from SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32102128/870122)
- SO: [Cannot get searchview in actionbar to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704661/870122)

The new searchable activity `ListActivity` is launched from a SearchView widget inside the App Bar in `MainActivity`. The new searchable activity is started but the search intent is missing (`onNewIntent` method is never called).

***Searchable.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

***AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<application
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".ui.ListActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        ...
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ListActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        ...
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

***MainActivity***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // setSupportActionBar
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);    
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

***ListActivity***

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate invoked");    //Log Printed
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent invoked");    //Log NOT Printed
    }
}
```

Consider that I have also replaced `getComponentName()` with `new ComponentName(this, ListActivity.class)` but got the same result: no errors, no intent query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [onNewIntent()'s documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)):

> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) flag when calling [startActivity(Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

`singleTop` only applies if the activity (in your case the `ListActivity`) is on top - instead of creating a new instance, it would reuse the existing one. However, if you are only searching from `MainActivity` (hitting back on `ListActivity` after a search), then you are destroying the `ListActivity` instance and then creating a new instance - leading to `onCreate()` being called, but not `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Thanks, but aargh, I see that I forgot to add here the launchmode, but it's indeed present in my code. Let me update the question. Unfortunately the answer doesn't apply...

Comment: Are you searching from within your `ListActivity`? Or always searching from `MainActivity`? Obviously when you hit back on your `ListActivity` that instance is destroyed and you create a new instance when you search again - again, not a new Intent to an existing Activity.

Comment: Updated my answer as well

Comment: Now I got the point. Everything was working well, but I simply was not reading the query in `onCreate` method using `getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)`. Not a difficult thing, but the android tutorial (the first link in my question) didn't even mention this!

Comment: I brought it up in the [Providing Search with SearchView video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OWmnYPX1uc) at [4 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OWmnYPX1uc&t=240). Still working on updating the documentation (or at least having a link to the video added!)

Answer (score 1):

The `onNewIntent` method is not called for the "first" `Intent` an activity receives. Have a look at the documentation http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent).

In your case you can just call `getIntent` in `onCreate` to get your search query:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is great, but the chosen one helped me more to get the whole picture!